# Подключиться к IP Камере

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Есть ASP net mvc сайт, необходимо реализовать подключение к IP Камере. В представлении набросал поля для IP адреса/Порта/Логина/Пароля.
Но как подключиться к удаленной камере не знаю. Подскажите что нужно использовать?
По функционалу нужно чтобы пользователь ввел данные по камере, нажал на кнопку подключиться, у него появилось видео с камеры.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить картинку с камеры нужно просто указать её ссылку трансляции. То-то и всего. Проблема только сделать так, чтобы эта ссылка заработала.

Дак вот, у IP камер есть собственный видеопоток и он имеет ссылку вида: rtsp://*логин*:*пароль*@*адрес камеры*:*порт*/*путь к потоку* (как пример: rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.200.11:554/Streaming/Channels/101). У каждой камеры этот адрес будет по умолчанию разный, поэтому обращайтесь к документации к камере или спрашивайте у саппорта производителя. Локальный ip камеры ещё зачастую пишут на самой камере, или же можно найти сразу все камеры в сети, воспользовавшись прогой по нахождению камер, идущей в комплекте с камерой на диске, или опять же трясти её с саппорта производителя.

Настроить камеру (адрес, логин, пароль, порт) можно через веб-интерфейс (как правило в каждой камере есть своя веб оболочка) зайдя в браузере по её адресу. Важно помнить, что ip камеры при этом должен быть в одной локальной сети с устройством, с которого вы будете к её веб-интерфейсу подключаться (например чтобы подключиться к камере с адресом 192.168.100.32, у компьютера может быть адрес 192.168.100.1).

Если поток с камеры будут смотреть больше чем с одного устройства единовременно, то нужно установить ретранслятор, ибо мощностей самой камеры хватает лишь на пару подключений к ней. Суть ретранслятора в том, что серверная машина начинает единолично постоянно забирать поток с камеры и уже затем, используя свои собственные мощности, раздавать поток всем желающим. Проще всего это сделать на линуксе с nginx'ом, в npm уже имеется такая технология, именуемая ffserver. Это самый примитивный, но и самый простой и надёжный способ. Когда ретранслятор будет настроен, поток можно будет забирать подключаясь к адресу сервера.

Также на том локальном устройстве, где подключены камеры, должен быть открыт порт, указанный у камеры в настройках, иначе сервер не сможет забрать с неё видеопоток. Порт нужно пробрасывать с одного сетевого устройства к другому, пока он не укажет на камеру. У каждой камеры отдельный порт подключения к ней.

Ну и под конец естественно нужно клиентское решение ввиде плеера для отображения rtsp трансляции. Я подобный проект делал под веб, поэтому не могу помочь с asp.

Немного упрощу вам жизнь:

- [RTSP ссылки](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=MFo4W-24FNGjmwXr5ayQDg&q=ip%20camera%20rtsp%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0&oq=ip%20camera%20rtsp%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)
- [Веб интерфейс](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=mV84W76pH8yosAHX47TQAQ&q=ip%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%20web%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81&oq=ip%20camera%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9)
- [ffserver для ретрансляции rtsp](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=YWw4W5KWEcSa6AT5_4fABg&q=ffmpeg%20rtsp%20server&oq=ffmgeg%20rtsp)
- [Проброс портов](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=c2w4W8-VM4Sb6ASvwo-gAg&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2&oq=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)
- [И инструкция, которую я сделал для персонала одной компании, подключающей ip камеры](http://onicio.ru/business/help)

Comment: не заметил сразу, что у вас сайт, в таком случае вам подойдёт flowplayer для просмотра трансляции